# WordPress Parent page slug in permalink

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi i am using WordPress salient theme and uber menu plugin for navigation. But i am facing issue that parent page slug not appearing in permalink.

> Like:

Post showing
/post-name
i want to show it like
/blog/post-name

> My permalink setting is

/%postname%/

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is the parent page an actual page or an archive listing?

Comment: Did you try adding /blog/ to the custom permalink structure?